# Basic Python Issue (UnboundLocalError: local variable 'normal' referenced before assignment)

Tags: python, variables

I am having a pretty basic issue and I know you guys will easily be able to spot the error.

Right now I am trying to write a script that calculates overtime pay for me.  I haven't written very much code so I am just trying to stick with basic problems for now.  I have went through code academy and I will be starting Learn Python the Hard way, however I think I need to just make more projects in order to better get an understanding.

This is my code right now.  I am confused as to why it thinks a variable hasn't been defined yet, because I clearly am defining the three variables I need at the top.

```
### California overtime payment calculator.


### Based on an 8 hour normal day, 1.5x day rate after 8 hours, and 2x pay after 12 hours.
### Enter your rate, then the number of hours you worked and you will get a result.



rate = raw_input("Enter your current rate:")

print "This is your rate: %s" % (rate)
normal = 0
overtime = 0
doubleOT = 0



def enteredHours():
        userInput = raw_input("Enter your hours for given day: ")

        if int(userInput) >= 12:
                print "Greater than 12"
                normal = normal + 8
                overtime = overtime + 4
                doubleOT = doubleOT + (userInput - 12)

        elif int(userInput) >= 8:
                print "Greater or equal to 8"
                normal = normal + 8
                overtime = overtime + (userInput - 8)

        elif int(userInput) < 8:
                normal = normal + userInput

        elif str(userInput) == "calculate":

                hoursTotal = normal + overtime + doubleOT
                print "Total amount of hours is: " + str(hoursTotal)

                payTotal = (normal * 250) + (overtime * 250 * 1.5) + (doubleOT * 250 * 2)
                print "Total amount of pay is: " + str(payTotal)
        return normal
        return overtime
        return doubleOT

        enteredHours()


enteredHours()
```

Comment: Could you provide the full traceback and error message?  Having the corresponding line numbers will help solve the issue as you have `normal` used (and redefined) in many places.

Answer (score 5):

This is a very common issue for beginners. Those variables are out of scope of the function.

Either define them inside of your function like so:

```
def enteredHours():
    normal = 0
    overtime = 0
    doubleOT = 0
```

or use the `global` keyword to put them in scope:

```
normal = 0
overtime = 0
doubleOT = 0

def enteredHours():
    global normal
    global overtime
    global doubleOT
```

Because you appear to be using these variables to accumulate over multiple invocations of the `enteredHours` function, you should choose the second option with the `global` keyword.

**EDIT:** You also have some other issues. Your code will return on the first `return` statement:

```
return normal #  exit function here
return overtime #  not executed!
return doubleOT #  not executed!
```

If you want to return all 3 values, you need to return them with the same return statement:

```
return normal, overtime, doubleOT
```

**EDIT #2**

Don't run your code recursively (by calling `enteredHours` at the end of the function - this statement isn't run anyway since the function exits at the return statement). Instead run it in a while loop:

```
def enteredHours():
    ...


while True:
    enteredHours()
```

The reason for this is that your stack grows with each recursive call, and eventually you will hit a "stack overflow" :)

Comment: Thank you!  This is very helpful!